# How to call a function created with Java (Spring) in a template Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am a beginner in Thymeleaf, I want to know how can I call a function created with Java in a Thymeleaf template ?

this is my function in Class named MyClass :

```
 public Double getPoint() throws ParseException
    {
        //code
       return somme;
     }
```

I tried this :

```
<tr th:each ="rep : ${Listall}">  
<th class="tabcos" th:text="${rep.point}"> </th>
```

I konw this return more than one result, I want only one result bcz my function return the sum of some fields.

Is there a way to get what I want ?
Thanks.

Comment: `${rep.point}` is a shortcut for `${rep.getPoint()}`.  You can call most java functions in this way.  Your question is pretty vague though.

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf is a template engine, it runs on client side and cannot directly run java code.

If you want dynamic behaviour on your template you can use JS.

All Java code will run on your server-side implementation and is usually called via http requests and a `@Controller` class in Spring-MVC.

To get started I recommend [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) Tutorial, it should help you get some things clear.